# Can you completely kill a big slime with a single detonation of TNT?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While playing a creative flat map the other day, I noticed something: It's basically impossible to kill a big slime with a single detonation of TNT? There's always some medium or small slimes left, regardless of how much TNT I use (even if I use a *lot*) due to the delay in spawning the smaller slimes. Is there some way of building a structure out of nothing but TNT blocks so that it will completely eradicate a big slime trapped within?

### E.g.

#### Trapped Slime

[image]

#### Construction

[image]

#### Ignition

[image]

#### Result

[image]

...2 medium slimes left!

Comment: I have no idea the solution, but this is quite the interesting endeavor.

Comment: Is having one detonation trigger another allowed?

Comment: @JohntheGreen of course, but you're only allowed 1 manual detonation.

Comment: I can't test anything.  They just hop right through my TNT walls.  :/

Comment: This question seems like a peculiar form of [Programming Puzzles/Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) with it's arbitrary restrictions and lack of an actual problem

Comment: @NickT A lot of the Minecraft questions are like that though, it's fun!

Comment: *You Monster!* ...

Comment: Why were you doing this in the first place? U jelly of the jelly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You just need a lot more of it.

[image: Setup]
[image: Explosion]
[image: Aftermath]

I got three or four large ones... Oops.

Comment: Are you sure this didn't actually launch the slime into space?

Comment: Which one did you ignite?

Comment: @fredley—I ignited the center of the base nearest the camera. I added a little freehand circle showing where I placed a redstone torch.

Answer (score 3):

If the TNT all exploded at the same time, then no. This is because it all hits the big slime and by the time it separates all the TNT is gone. You could use repeaters/redstone torches to have a few delayed TNT explosions. Then there would be only one ignition and it could still kill the slime.

Comment: I get this much, but using *only* TNT can you engineer a suitable delay?

Comment: TNT alone, no. Unless of course your some kind of Minecraft physics genius. without the use of Restone you could make obsidian channels, or something that controls which TNT explodes which other TNT. It kind of hard to explain, but I hope you understand.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. TNT triggering TNT causes a very short ‘fuse’ on the target, so all the TNT near the slime will be quickly gone, and anything distant won't have time to fall down on the slime. Note that a stack of TNT can be triggered from the bottom and will chain all the way to the top without falling away — it's *very* fast.

I found that I could cause such stacked TNT to fall further before exploding by layering it with stone — the stone above the TNT prevents it from hopping upward when triggered, allowing it to fall down sooner. This was not enough to kill a slime, but I didn't design the structure very thoughtfully.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to completely kill a large slime with a single piece of TNT.

This is because slimes have multiple stages to their health, and TNT can only take away one, thus dividing the slime.

As in the photo above with the multiple pieces of TNT, that works because multiple blasts can then kill the smaller slimes after the big slime has been split.